# App routing works but only from internal navigation, not browser address bar

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have built an angular 11 app with routing modules. If you start the app by going to the domain url it will do the right thing and go to the "dashboard" path. Once there, I can use a menu with many links to click on and the app will navigate to where it should.

`http://localhost:4200` -> brings me to 'dashboard' path

`http://localhost:4200/dashboard` -> brings me to 'dashboard' path

But I cannot type another path in the browser address bar that is valid (and I can get to via routerlink or code nvagation) as:

`http://localhost:4200/management/user-management`
This works through internal application navigation but, if I type the above in the browser address bar I will not get there, it is as if I typed `http://localhost:4200/dashboard`

router code below:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
    component: fromCore.DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'management',
    loadChildren: () => import('./management/management.module').then(m => m.ManagementModule),
    canLoad: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'inventory',
    loadChildren: () => import('./inventory/inventory.module').then(m => m.InventoryModule),
    canLoad: [AuthenticationGuard]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
```

management module code:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    component: fromContainers.ManagementComponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: 'user-management',
            component: fromContainers.UserManagementComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'create',
            component: fromContainers.UserCreateComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'edit/:id',
            component: fromContainers.UserEditComponent,
            canActivate: [fromGuards.UserExistsGuard]
        },
        {
            path: 'change-password/:id',
            component: fromContainers.ChangePasswordComponent,
            canActivate: [fromGuards.UserExistsGuard]
        } 
    ]}
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

**ANSWER**

There is nothing wrong with the above.  My problem was that I had forgotten that I had a ngrx effect that I was running from the AppComponent (the startup component). It was dispatching an action that triggered an effect that was always navigating to the dashboard.  I have now made sure the effect has the intended path.

Comment: Have you tried using the hash location strategy?

Comment: @ sofa_maniac, No, can't say that I understand it.  But really shouldn't this just work?  I will look into it...

Comment: Maybe `canLoad` fails? Could you replicate the problem in a StackBlitz demo?

Comment: So I have figured out my problem. It really amounts to one hand doesn't know what the other is doing... I will edit my question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an angular guy  but very  similar thing happened to me Flask-routing ,

My solution was (adapting to your url) typing like this :

```
http://localhost:4200/dashboard/management/user-management
```

May be worth to try..

Comment: Because of the way I'm lazy loading modules and the structure would just not be right for the site I won't try this.

Comment: @Irv Lennert , I just meant after running your development server (http://localhost:4200)  , type in your local browser to that url, without changing any line in your code. And verify if you can reach that user-management sub page , with this way.. If you see a live page under  `http://localhost:4200/dashboard/management/user-management`  ,  but not under `http://localhost:4200/management/user-management`  , then it gives you an idea / hint that you have some kind of sub-directory  problem in your code...

Comment: Thank you, I have found the problem and I will update my question.  Thanks very much for your effort and time!